# Is offering to complete a coding challenge in cover letter useful?

Tags: applications

I've been trying to relocate into a different country (my partner lives there), but until now I've been unsuccessful. Currently I have been employed for three years, but my work history before was bad (2 year gap) and I assume this is a big factor as to why many of my applications remain unanswered.

My current job and job offer I refused were both offered after I've got their attention by impressing them with my solution. A lot of people criticize such a request for a variety of reasons, I do however like them. I can show them (at least as far as that's possible with coding challenges) my dedication, skills, problem solving and creative thinking.

I've beginning to think if I should include a sentence in which I offer doing such a coding challenge directly in my cover letter. Would this be a useful plan in my job search?

Comment: It seems about equivalent to saying you'd be willing to do a telephonic interview, or consent to a background check.

Comment: If you've been working for the same company for the last 3 years, you may be overestimating the effect of the gap on your applications (I'd assume it would be a minor factor, at most). But I can only speculate as to why you don't get responses (not getting responses to a large percentage of applications is not uncommon even with a solid spotless background).

Comment: I would put a link to some sort of coding in your resume or cover letter (preferably resume) if you want to show off your skills. That way hiring managers can decide for themselves whether to check it out. As a side note, I would also address your two year gap in your cover letter. In general, if it's likely that the employer will have a concern about something, you want to address it upfront. It will show that you acknowledge that it can be seen as a potential issue and allows you to provide an explanation on why it wouldn't affect your employment with them.

Answer (score 13):

If I, as an technical interviewer, am interested in seeing what you can do in a coding challenge, I am going to have one prepared and make it part of the hiring process all my applicants go through. Otherwise, there is no way I'm going to try to come up with one just for you. That's a lot of work on my end that I do not have time for. So offering to take a coding challenge in your cover letter is not going to move me one way or the other. I either already have one planned, or I'm not going to do it at all. Leave the sentence out of your cover letter.

If you are eager to show off how well you can code, one thing that can help you is including a link to work you have done in a public code repository like GitHub or BitBucket. It won't take me long to go through that, and you can use that to showcase your skills. If it is interesting, I may even ask you about it in the interview, so come prepared to discuss what you have done.

Comment: If OP is/has applied to software jobs chances are he already has a Github account to show his work (if not OP should)

Answer (score 7):

> I've beginning to think if I should include a sentence in which I offer doing such a coding challenge directly in my cover letter. Would this be a useful plan in my job search?

*Hardly.* It's not that it will harm your application, but most likely won't help wither.

Each company is different; some require code tests and others don't. **You offering to do such test will have no difference in the fact that they will or will not require you such.**

If you wish to make your application more outstanding, try tailoring your resume to include relevant things for the roles you seek, leaving out other non-essential information for that specific application, or perhaps making your cover letter more convincing in other ways.

Also, being in a job for three years is a good sign (of work stability and such) so perhaps try focusing more on things like that, than on the two-year gap and other not-so-related jobs you had before that.

Comment: Anything in a cover letter that doesn't help hurts.